# How do I know the current catalog name of the Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I connected to the Oracle DB with SqlPlus. How to know the current catalog name?

Comment: The term "catalog" (in terms of the SQL standard) would map to a pluggable database in Oracle. Is that what you are looking for? Or do you mean the current "schema"?

Comment: I mean the first word before point (catalog_name.userid(schema).table_name). Is it dbname?

Comment: You can't have an identifier with three parts in Oracle. You can only use `schema_name.table_name`

Comment: You can have three parts e.g. to identify a column name ([Syntax for Schema Objects and Parts in SQL Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Syntax-for-Schema-Objects-and-Parts-in-SQL-Statements.html)); but not with an extra part before the schema. You might want the database name, or possibly instance, or service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Term 'catalog name' isn't correct or clear. You mean `schema_name`.

Schema name you can get for example like this:

```
SELECT sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' )
FROM dual;
```

**Catalog** in Oracle DB context is used for **catalog view** or **data dictionary view**. It is the set of Oracle's views. More information: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables014.htm